# How to redirect part of standard output from a shell command

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the below shell commands to generate the ssh key and to add the public key to authorized keys. But, I want to redirect all the out put of this command to a file while I have to get the prompt generated by these commands to enter output.

```
ssh-keygen -f /home/$cu/.ssh/${ssh_key}_rsa -t rsa -N ''
# Add Public Key to authorized keys
ssh-copy-id -i /home/$cu/.ssh/${ssh_key}_rsa.pub $Linux_User@$Linux_Machine
```

Could you please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Eh? The prompt isn't on stdout at all. A well-written program (and OpenSSH certainly follows these conventions) will prompt either to stderr or direct to the TTY, **not** to stdout. A prompt for a password, **in particular**, will go direct to the TTY.

Comment: Can you reformulate the question to let someone reproduce the problem you're facing, as opposed to being written in a way that depends on an incorrect assumption?

Comment: (By the way, what's the `vi` tag doing here? I don't see anything in title or text that describes how an editor is involved).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy About 5 seconds of checking shows ssh-keygen prompts to stderr.

Comment: sure, thanks for inputs. reformulating the question.

Comment: ...so, if the prompts are printed to stderr, then you can redirect stdout to a file and still see the stderr. So where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for is probably a command called `tee` which will split a stream into 2. Although you can get very complicated with it, the most common use is to write something to a file while also letting the streams still print out like normal just like what you are looking for.

```
ssh-keygen -f /home/$cu/.ssh/${ssh_key}_rsa -t rsa -N '' | tee -a $log_file

ssh-copy-id -i /home/$cu/.ssh/${ssh_key}_rsa.pub $Linux_User@$Linux_Machine | tee -a $log_file
```

Comment: Aside: Lots of missing quotes here. That's true in the question, too, but ideally an answer should try to showcase good practices.